# How do I structure DynamoDB keys / indices

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to set up what I think is a relative simple structure in DDB, but I am finding the docs very confusing and my experiments keep running into problems.  I'm hoping someone can help point me in the right direction on how I should structure this

I have three different object classes.  Each has a unique, static id number; a non-unique date identifier that can change; and a set of other attributes (non-unique, changeable).  The set of other attributes is different for each class

I need to be able to retrieve objects by id; retrieve all objects of a specific class; retrieve all objects within a range of dates; and update an object's date and other attributes.  I may need to search by other attributes later.

What is the best way to structure tables / keys / secondary indices for this situation?

So far I have tried:

1. A single table, hash key = object type, range key = id, GlobalSecondaryIndex = date as hash key.

   - GSI doesn't support 'between' operator for date lookups.
     (KeyConditionExpression=Key('date').between(d_min, d_max))
2. One table for each class, hash key = id, range key = date

   - when I update an item whose date has changed, I end up with a second record as the primary key is composed of both id and date
3. One table for each class, hash key = id, no range key.  GSI = date as hash key

   - GSI doesn't support 'between' operator for date lookups.
4. One table for each class, hash key = id, no range key.  GSI = date as range key

   - GSI requires a hash key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I need to be able to retrieve objects by id;
2. retrieve all objects of a specific class;
3. retrieve all objects within a range of dates;
4. update an object's date and other attributes.

*I may need to search by other attributes later* = add more GSI's.

### Base Table

Fulfills use-case 1 + 2 + 4, assuming you know the class when searching by id.

| PK | SK | GSIPK | GSISK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TYPECLASS | TYPE#ID123 | 1 | 2023-07-06T00:00:000 |
| TYPECLASS | TYPE#ID233 | 1 | 2023-07-06T00:00:000 |
| TYPECLASS | TYPE#ID111 | 1 | 2023-07-06T00:00:000 |

### GSI

Fulfills use-case 4. This makes the assumption your writes won't exceed 1000 WCU, if they will, you will need to [write shard](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-gsi-sharding.html) the `GSIPK`

| GSIPK | GSISK | PK | SK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-07-06T00:00:000 | TYPECLASS | TYPE#ID123 |
| 1 | 2023-07-06T00:00:000 | TYPECLASS | TYPE#ID233 |
| 1 | 2023-07-06T00:00:000 | TYPECLASS | TYPE#ID111 |

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.  What advantage does the 'TYPE#' part of the SK give, if we already have the type as the PK?

Comment: No added value actually, I declared that answering request 1… then when I reiterated for 2 I changed my design and got lazy and didnt remove it 